Why would tightening screws on a GE Arc-fault breaker cause "frizzing" sound and flickering lights? Once applied torque is removed all is good
Background. House built new in 2017, using GE Goldmark panel. All was done well and checked well with no issues. Needed to go into the panel recently, for some unrelated work.... and decided (per good practice) to check the screw tightness of all my breakers. All of them were still tight, but when I applied checking torque to one of the breakers ( 20A, GE THQL1120AF2, powering mostly lights)....while torque was applied... I heard a "frizzing" sound and lights began to flicker. I immediately stopped and removed the screw torque.... and all went back to "normal". Thinking this was maybe a fluke....I checked tightness again and as long as torque was applied to the screws, the "frizzing" sound again appeared and the lights again flickered. When I released the torque all was fine. I'm thinking more its a bad breaker vs wiring issues. Or if it's a wiring issues, can it be local wiring to the breaker?

Most people do not take a chance working in a panel with the power still on.  It will be okay until you slip up.  Darwin Awards are full of stories who said they do not slip up, till they did.

That's not my question..... I know the risks and take appropriate actions. I would prefer some insight on these Arc Fault breakers especially if someone had specific experience with this brand and model number to see if a trending answer applies. Thanks.

I would guess that applying torque with the power on, it moves the electrical connection of the breaker to the panel just enough to cause a not perfect connection being maintain.  Applying torque shifts the breaker body over a bit.

I know some electricians work with live circuits: the utility workers cut the live 240V lines to our house when we had our heavy-up, so the neighbors didn't lose power for the time, then reconnected them live. Is it common practice for licensed electricians to torque the business end of breakers when the breakers are live and on?


but when I applied checking torque to one of the breakers ( 20A, GE THQL1120AF2, powering mostly lights)....while torque was applied... I heard a "frizzing" sound and lights began to flicker

Don't do that with the breaker turned on.
What's happening is the torque is pushing the breaker sideways at the bus clip, causing it to make poor contact at the bus clip.  Also the terminal you are tightening is energized when the breaker is on.  That means so is the tool you are holding.
You are better off doing that with the breaker held in your hand. Every breaker specifies a torque.  You do not have a calibrated arm and you need to use a torque screwdriver.

Without actually disecting the breaker, I'd say you moved slightly the internal contact leg connected to the screw you were tightening. Since the lights were on, you'd notice "frizzing and flickering" until the tension was released. Maybe the other breakers were not supplying current at the time so no symptoms were noticed. I can't say I've experienced this, even though I've worked with these breakers, because I've never done this with a hot load screw on a breaker. I would atleast turn the individual breaker off before checking the load screw.

For clarity....all breakers were torque checked under power and only this one acted like this. The other breakers had no lights on their circuit but were silent nonetheless when torque was applied "hot" ( used fully insulated square-bit screwdriver, no rings or watches worn, etc.)  No doubt,....if we're going any further by taking breaker out or disconnecting leads from the breaker..... ..it would for sure require killing the power first.

I agree with Jack. Tightening things twists them. And commodity electronics have a bell curve of reliability, with apparently good items having a slight problem that doesn't show in the manufacturer tests but still will show in new items under certain unusual circumstances. That particular breaker probably has both: lower portion of the bell curve and a twisting motion under torque led to slight connection looseness inside the breaker or to the bus bar.

So Triplefault.... and asking this  next question respectfully so the written word doesn't get misinterpreted--> should I simply leave this alone as I wouldn't have found it by tightness-checking a dead panel?...and.... it seems anyway all is OK after I release the torque on the (proven-to-be tight) screw. Leave it alone?

@WilFerch  I would operate it, reset it,  and leave it alone.

UPDATE......based on these discussion comments....I went back to the panel and tried this---> even with the screws tight....and with the panel still energized...all I had to do was touch or try to wiggle the connected wires to the breaker "just a smidge"....and the "frizzing" and flickering occured again.  Not good. Either the breaker is bad or has a weak/loose connection to the bus, or maybe even a wiring problem close to the breaker. Next step will be to de-energize everything and take the breaker out to check it and the localized connections. Thanks all.

@WilFerch   Wiggling wires and getting weird noises/results is one of the main tests for find a broken wire inside of wire insulation.  Wire is broken, but the wire insulation holds it together enough most of the time so you need get power some times.  Would have a second breaker and some similar wire for replacements.  And some wire nuts/wagos.

Turn the problem breaker OFF. Torque to spec. Turn the breaker ON. See if wiggling wires still causes any problems. If no problems then your problem was that the wires were not tight enough. If it still have problems then you either have a flaky wire (e.g., nicked a bit somewhere so wiggling causes a disconnect or a short) or a bad breaker.
